# How to import file to Mindstorm Programmer?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software

I got a Mindstorm set a year ago and I stumbled across a build which looked really cool! I finished the building part then I downloaded the program file but I couldn’t import it.

I have a MacBook with ‘MINDSTORM 1.0.1 Home Edition’. So the problem is I can’t import the file (.ev3) to the application and it doesn’t allow me to.

Any suggestions how to import .ev3 file to MINDSTORM 1.0.1 Home (MacBook)?

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot or a more detailed description of the issue? Specifically the "doesn't allow me to" part would be interesting, as it could be that the file type does not match, the file itself is corrupted, or a number of other possible causes.

Comment: "Mindstorm 1.0.1" sounds very vague and could possibly be a NXT programming environment - which wouldn't take EV3 files. You may want to add as much information as possible, as @zovits said, screenshots are a good start; but also which kit you bought; if the robot you stumbled upon is from the Internet, a link to it might help too.